# How does Google track me without using mobile my internet data plan?

Tags: google-maps, tracking

I'm developing an app that can shows all the bus lines in my city, i'd like to show if the bus is crowded or not, and even get the bus position by another user that is inside it.

But I don't want to use all the internet plan from my users, I see that Google does that, it knows when a restaurant or bar has people there, knows if a street is congested, and also get your path history.

I'm not asking for all the code, but kind of how does Google does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google *will* be using mobile data when it tracks that - but I don't imagine sending  a GPS co-ordinate every 30 mins will use much data.

And if it did - then Google will probably store that data offline and upload it later when a WiFi connection is available.

Comment: Yeah, I did some calculations here, if a send a json with, lat, lng, user_id and time, its about 75 bytes, sending it every 10 minutes, in a month would use 3,24 MB